# Unable to concatenate strings using + operator in python

Tags: python, string, string-concatenation

I have written the below python program.

```
var = '28'
express = "r'\b" + var + "\b'"
print(express)
```

I expected to get `r'\b28\b'` but I am getting `r'28'`.

I don't understand why. Can someone please help me with it? Besides `var` is supposed to be a user input so I need to know some way to print `express` correctly.

Comment: Which is to say, concatenation is working fine. The question is, why are you trying to generate this string?

Answer (score 1):

`\b` is the escape sequence for backspace. If you want literal `\b` in your result, use a raw string to prevent the escape sequence from being processed.

```
var = '28'
express = r"r'\b" + var + r"\b'"
print(express)
```